# replacing vowels with "idig" using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

It doesn't have to use a list comprehension, this is just the solution I've come up with and I'd like to understand how to write the list comprehension so the syntax is correct and it works.

```
charl = list(word)
charl = [i for i in charl if i not in vowels else "idig"]
print (charl)
```

thanks for your help :)

edit:

the rest of my code for this part is this:

```
def gibberish_converter (self):
        gib = ""
        listeng = self.string.split()
        for word in listeng:
            if word[0] not in vowels:
                charl = list(word)
                charl = [i for i in charl if i not in vowels else "idig"]
                newword = "".join(charl)
                gib = gib + " " + newword
            elif word[0] in vowels:
                gib = "idig" + word
        print("gibberish is: " + gib)
```

Comment: Could you please display more of your code so that I know what you're attempting to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
charl = list("word")
charl = [i if i not in "aeiouAEIOU" else "idig" for i in charl]
print(charl)
```

Edit: Just saw the edit in your question. Let me know if this answer is still useful for you, otherwise I will delete this.

Edit2: All good.

Comment: thats perfect thanks idk why i had such a mental block